# RPI_PICO_TimerInterrupt: Any way to set timer to zero to get a known starting time?

Tags: timer, interrupt, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm using RPI_PICO_TimerInterrupt library for a Raspberry Pi Pico, in the Arduino IDE 2 environment.
The RPI_PICO_TimerInterrupt library by khoih-prog covers what I want to do; one detail is escaping me.
The library URL is https://github.com/khoih-prog/RPI_PICO_TimerInterrupt.

I have a GPS receiver's 1 pulse per second output connected to an input pin and firing a hardware interrupt.  That works fine.

I created an interrupt timer:
RPI_PICO_Timer elementTimer(1); // Three timers are available, this is using 1
and attached it to an interrupt service routine in setup()
elementTimer.attachInterruptInterval(TIMER_RATE, TimerISR);
The timer works as advertised and calls TimerISR.

I would like to restart the timing clock inside the hardware interrupt service routine, so that timing begins accurately as the hardware ISR is fired.  I assume that this involves setting some variable to zero or invoking a "reset()" method in the library.

I don't see that the library includes a way to do that--am I missing something?

I tried the .restartTimer() method (this is for restarting a stopped timer, I realize that; but I tried) and I tried reinstantiating the timer object inside the hardware ISR.
Neither changed the "phase" of the timer.

It seems to me that there must be some way to run the timer as a stopwatch but I can't find it.

My overall goal is to subdivide the GPS receiver's PPS signal into an interrupt that can fire a desired number of times each second, starting at the PPS rising edge.

Thank you.

David AD8Y

Comment: I don't know how that library works, but the hardware has one 64-bit counter that always counts up at a 1MHz rate. The hardware has 4 alarm registers that can generate an interrupt when the bottom 32bits matches a specified value. That library probably uses these alarms to multiplex the users' timers. Basically, there's nothing to "zero" here. You'll have to do that in your code, or read the hardware counter and derive a relative offset.  It sounds like you could start a "short" timer when you get a rising edge interrupt from the PPS, and then repeat that short interval a few more times.

Comment: Thanks.  I purchased a textbook of Pi Pico programming, Harry Fairhead's "Programming The Raspberry Pi Pico In C."  It has a chapter on interrupts and another on timers, but doesn't discuss a library method for the function that I'm after.  I will continue looking for those 4 registers and a way to set them to zero in the hardware interrupt service routing.